# How to do flutter automation test for flutter web applications using webdriver package and chromedriver which is an alternative to selenium testing

Tags: flutter, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, webdriver, flutterdriver

How to do  flutter automation test for flutter web applications using webdriver package and chromedriver which is an alternative to selenium testing.

I have succesfully installed chrome driver for my chrome browser on windows( chrome for Automation Testing)

but unable to launch my app using  "flutter drive --target=test_driver/app.dart"  but it is always launching web app turned mobile app on the default chrome browser and not on  my chrome for testing or chrome driver and I am unable to automation test..

Please help in connecting my application with my chrome for Testing browser and I should be able to test my app on chromne for testing browser.